Logistic regression for evaluating explanatory power of features - interpretation of score and confidence
I want help with figuring out whether my analysis is sound.
My objective is to evaluate the explanatory power of a certain set of features for a binary classification problem.
My current strategy is to:

select features that are non-correlating and statistically significant (t-test)
use these features to fit a logistic regression model (sklearn)
compare strength in features by looking at the coefficients
evaluate the explanatory power of these features by getting the confidence values from the decision function, and the score - testing the model on the train data.

Here is where I'm uncertain. My gut tells me it's always wrong to test on train data (duh). But my brain tells me it makes sense in this scenario. I want to know how many of the data points are distinguishable based on the information from my features - not how it would react to unseen data.
Roughly, this is my thought process:

High confidence, high score => features are good
High confidence, low
score => features are misleading
Low confidence, high score =>
features are informative but not that strong
Low confidence, low
score => features are uninformative

Is this analysis scheme sound?

(1) What notion of confidence and score are you using? (2) This is absolutely a case where overfitting can occur. Models can "tell stories" based on random in-sample relationships, which break down out of sample because they were random in the first place. I would argue that explanatory power only makes sense if a feature helps us predict new data better; otherwise it is just a case of shooting at the wall, painting targets around the holes and claiming high accuracy.

@StephanKolassa Thanks for the comment. (1) I averaged confidence values retrieved from the decision function (sklearn's logistic regression documentation) for each class. Score is the accuracy on the train data... (2) Yes, this is what my gut tells me as well. However, my dataset is small (250) and very context-dependent so I can't generalize in either case. Focus is on this particular instance. I want to argue something like "this is as good as it could possibly get with these features, hence we have no reason to believe they're reliable, despite low p-values" - does that make sense to you?

Your first bullet point is already a bad idea. It's known as bivariate screening and has many problems that have been discussed here before.

@PeterFlom Thanks for the comment. I know there are problems with this and I've tried to find other alternatives, but basically all previous research in my specific field to this. I'll have to stick with that part for the time being. Just out of curiosity, what would you recommend instead?

(1) Unfortunately, the documentation is rather unclear on what they mean by "confidence". It seems to involve the classification threshold, which I argue should not be part of the modeling step. Without knowing what that concept truly is, I would be careful about interpreting it. ...

... Accuracy is a very problematic KPI, and note that there are proper scoring rules which are a much better concept than accuracy.

I would suggest subject matter knowledge and careful thought. But, if you want something automated, LASSO isn't bad.

(2) If your dataset is small, then that is more reason to be careful about overfitting, which is what an evaluation in-sample will lead to. Context dependency I get. But I would still work with some kind of test set, even if it is only cross-validation.

Thank you all for your help and insightful comments. This is my first time doing an analysis like this so I am very grateful for your kind and thorough responses.
I added cross-validation to the pipeline and will consider LASSO if I get the possibility onward to redo the statistical analysis later (this is "only" my MA thesis but it might figure in a future publication). The confidence values are still part of the analysis but I'm very careful with the interpretation. Regarding score, I switched to F1-score, but I'm curious, do you have any opinions on pseudo R2-scores?

The analysis scheme is far from sound, in more ways than are noted in comments. It's particularly bad with a binary outcome model.
First, pre-selection of features based on single-variable models is bad in general and particularly bad in binary regression, in which there can be omitted-variable bias if any outcome-associated predictor isn't included in the model, even if the omitted predictor is uncorrelated with the included predictor(s). See this page, for example. Each of your single-variable models is thus unreliable to start.
Second, to "compare strength in features by looking at the coefficients" would only work well if all features are expressed in the same scales. For example, the coefficient value for a distance expressed in millimeters will be much different (by a factor of one million) from that for the same distance expressed in kilometers. Or if some predictors are continuous and others categorical, how do you compare their coefficients?
What you want is a measure of how much of the explanatory power of the model comes from a predictor. Frank Harrell discusses this in Section 5.1.3 of Regression Modeling Strategies. With a binary regression you can use the ratio of the partial likelihood ratio chi-square statistic to the total model chi-square as a measure of relative importance among predictors. That approach is illustrated both in that Section and in Chapter 11.
Third, the "decision function" isn't properly part of the model, if I understand your use of the term correctly. A binary regression model estimates the probability of the outcome as a function of predictor variables. The decision function is applied afterwards, based on a probability cutoff that represents the relative costs of different types of (mis)classification. Evaluate the quality and calibration of the probability model.
Fourth, you say "I want to know how many of the data points are distinguishable based on the information from my features." That might tell you how well your current model works on your current data, but it wouldn't provide any generalizable information. If you have a sufficiently complex model you might be able to fit your current data almost perfectly, but in a way that bears little relationship to underlying reality. See Section 2.2.2 of An Introduction to Statistical Learning for the bias-variance tradeoff that's involved.
Fifth, there are some types of testing on training data that are acceptable, provided that you understand the limitations. Cross-validation was mentioned in comments. Another approach is bootstrapping, taking multiple samples each of the same size as your data set, with replacement, from the original data set. That mimics the sampling process that led to taking your original data set from the underlying population.
You repeat the entire modeling process on each bootstrap sample, evaluate the performance of each model on its corresponding bootstrap sample and on the full data set, and compare the performance. If your modeling process tends to overfit, then the average performance of models on their corresponding bootstrap samples will be better than their average performance on the full data set. You can thus estimate the overfitting of the full model and correct for it. That process can also be used to evaluate model calibration.
This process doesn't validate the model itself; it validates the model-building process. Unless you have tens of thousands of cases, however, bootstrapping or multiple rounds of cross-validation tend to work better than train-test split-sample validation. With smaller numbers of cases you end up both fitting the model poorly and having insufficient power to test it. See this web page.
Finally, see Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies for many more suggestions about how you could improve your approach for building and evaluating models.

Thank you so much for your thorough answer. I'll have to ask for some clarification though.
(1) "uncorrelated to the other predictor(s)..." - I might have misunderstood something, but aren't predictors for LR supposed to be uncorrelated? I thought minimizing collinearity was a good idea to do beforehand. Am I wrong in this?
(2) The features are all continuous and scaled using sklearn's StandardScaler. It should be ok to look at the coefficients then, right?
Thanks again.

@sualc99 collinearity isn't usually a big problem. Unless it's perfect, it can lead to wider confidence intervals for coefficients of correlated predictors but it doesn't affect predictive performance. You might want to group a set of collinear predictors into a single predictor; that's one form of "data reduction" covered in Section 4.7 of Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies. If all features are continuous and were centered to 0 and scaled to the same standard deviation then coefficients are less misleading but still need to be considered in the context of the entire model.
